Как добавить пагинации класс активности swiper slider при просморенном слайде?
 - картинка как должно выглядеть
Как добавить класс активности к пагинаци при просмотренном слайде и наоборот убрать, когда отмотали обратно
Swiper slider
Может можно кастомный progress bar сделать как-то
Была бы очень благодарен за написание функции
Вот мой код
var swiper = new Swiper(".repair-calc_slider", {
navigation: {
  nextEl: ".repair-calc-next",
  prevEl: ".repair-calc-prev",
},
pagination: {
    el: ".repair-calc-pagination",
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + "</span>";
    },
  },

});

Получить активный буллит, получить все буллиты и при событии slideChange проверять - пока итерируемый буллит не равен - активному - добавлять нужный класс, а затем - наоборот удалять.


let swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  pagination: {
    el: ".repair-calc-pagination",
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function(index, className) {
      return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + "</span>";
    },
  },
});

swiper.on('slideChange', function() {
  const bullets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-pagination-bullet'));
  const current = document.querySelector('.swiper-pagination-bullet-active');
  let currentAction = 'add';
  document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-pagination-bullet').forEach(bullet => {
    if (bullet === current) currentAction = 'remove';
    bullet.classList[currentAction]('castom-current');
  });
});
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active,
.castom-current {
  background: red!important;
  opacity: 1!important;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination repair-calc-pagination"></div>

</div>




Спасибо огромное
